# Laravel add custom where clause to Route

Tags: regex, laravel

We have a multiple `route` in `laravel` and one of our url we have this url:

```
http://sample.com/U9JD1
```

as our short urls, here this shorted url string length is fixed by 5 character and that could be both of `string` and `number` like with `U9JD1`

now how can i use `where` clause in this route:

```php
Route::get('{shortCode?}', function ($shortCode) {
    
});
```

Here I should combine 3 conditions in `where` clause

thanks so much

Comment: Use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)?!

Comment: can you provide the format that on which you are generating the short code

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/user/{name}', function ($name) {
  //
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

or

```
Route::get('/user/{name}', function ($name) {
//
})->whereAlphaNumeric('name');
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: Could you quote the key section of the reference? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Hossein MohammadHosseini so where are `3` conditions in `where` clause